# create an array with for loop strategy in cplex

Tags: arrays, csv, for-loop, cplex, opl

I know I ask a lot of questions about reading CSV file and coding it in CPLEX. But now my question is about a strategy. As I explained before I have a CSV file and I want to read it in a CPLEX. My question this time is that: I want to use a for loop to create an array in CPLEX from CSV file and I don't know how? This time I need to use for loop, not any other methods and I want to know is it possible or not:
My code so far is:

```
range demand = 1..10;
int index[demand];
 int weight[demand];
execute {

  var f = new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
  var data = f.readline();
  while (!f.eof) {
   var data = f.readline().split(",");
   if (data.length == 2)
   for (var i=1; i<=demand.length; i++){
     index[i].add(Opl.intValue(data[0]));
     weight[i].add(Opl.intValue(data[1]));

  }   
    writeln(index);
    writeln(weight);
}
}
```

The problem is that I get [00..0] values for both index and weight. 
The weight file is attached as a picture:
[weight file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0XUR.png)

I need I ask so many questions about this problem but I need this time that I use for loop and not define any tuple. I want to define each array separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in your code. If the code does not do what you want, it may help to add `writeln(...)` statements to trace what the code is actually doing. Then you can probably figure out these things yourself.

In your case there are a number of issues:

1. You are trying to use property `demand.length` but that property is undefined. You can see this by adding `writeln(demand.length)` to your code. So the condition `i<=demand.length` is never true and that loop is never executed.
2. You execute the loop over `i` for *each* line in the CSV file although each line in the CSV gives you only *one* entry in the array.
3. Even if your loop would have worked, you are trying to call function add() on a plain integer (each entry in the array is an integer). Integer numbers don't have such a property. So your loop would have raised an error.

The correct code to read your arrays from CSV would be this:

```
range demand = 1..10;
int index[demand];
int weight[demand];

execute {

  var f = new IloOplInputFile("weight.csv");
  var data = f.readline();
  var i = 1;
  while (!f.eof) {
    var data = f.readline().split(",");
    if (data.length == 2) {
      index[i] = Opl.intValue(data[0]);
      weight[i] = Opl.intValue(data[1]);
      i = i + 1;
    }
  }
  writeln(index);
  writeln(weight);
}
```